# Directory for Spring boot additional location parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-config

I am trying override few of the properties in my spring boot application. The properties are spread across mutiple yml files within the same directory and hence i would like to specify spring.config.additional-location parameter with the value of directory..

spring.config.additional-location=file:///Mydirectory/

But the application is not able to load the configs. If I explicitly specify the file name, the properties are getting overwritten

spring.config.additional-location=file:///Mydirectory/application.yml

Is it possible to load all the files available in a directory using spring.config.additional-location? If yes, please let me know

Comment: multiple yml files? what are those names? by default spring will check only for `application.yml` file in any location

Comment: We have multiple modules and the file names will be application-{module}.yml

Comment: then you need to specify them, sow an example or code will try to suggest best approach

Comment: Oh.. When passing the config location i should explicitly mention the module name also is it?

Comment: mvn clean test -P{project} -Dspring.config.additional-location='/Desktop/myconfigs/‘

The files in myconfigs are:

application-module1.yml
application-module2.yml
application-module3.yml